# Quake2 installation

Tags: software-installation, games

I'm new to Ubuntu but have made good progress (including XBMC/Gotham (very cool)) until attempting to install the game.
System is: Intel motherboard QD965GF, 4G Ram, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have the original Quake II (quake2) cdrom (for Windows 95 or NT 4.0) and have recently installed it on an XP based computer with no problems.

I installed "Quake II" from the Ubuntu Software Center (shows as "Version quake 2 7" from there.)

The command:

`sudo lshw -class disk` returns:

```
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST90811AS
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 3.AA
       serial: 5NH137DG
       size: 55GiB (60GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=0008d34d

  *-cdrom
       description: DVD reader
       product: DVD C  DH52C2S
       vendor: ATAPI
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: NP57
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

(please note that the disk is in the drive as the last line above shows `status=nodisk`) and the DVD drive is fine as it plays audio CDs and DVDs.

`game-data-packager quake2` returns:

```
to make quake2-full-data:
game-data-packager quake2 [--full] [<full game>] [<patch>]
        <full game>: path to CD-ROM mount point or baseq2 directory
        <patch>: path to q2-3.20-x86-full-ctf.exe
```

The system returns messages such as

```
using /dev/cdrom as CD-ROM block device to rip music
/usr/games/game-data-packager: 'cdparanoia' is required for this target.
Please install the following packages:
and try again.
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/tmp/game-data-packager.E0cjlv’: Directory not empty"
```

At this point, I'm at a loss.  Would someone be willing to access my system and attempt this installation?  Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do the same thing when I tried to install Quake 2.

You need to install the following in the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cdparanoia vorbis-tools
```

Vorbis tools includes oggenc which is required to package the ogg files.

Once those are installed now you will need to rip the music from your cd. Be sure to set the directory using

```
$ cd
```

Now once you have run that run this command to begin creating the music package.

```
$ game-data-packager quake2 --music /dev/cdrom
```

Next we will be installing the game-data-full package which contains all of the game files required to run the game. Except the way Ubuntu works is that it separates music in 2 different directories. Instead we will be installing from another directory.

You will need [q2-3.20-x86-full-ctf.exe](http://www.fileplanet.com/123342/download/Quake-2-Patch-v3.20-%28Full-CTF%29). Run this command after downloading q2-3.20-x86-full-ctf.exe.

```
$ game-data-packager quake2 --full /media/your-user-name/quake2 path-to-q2-3.20-x86-full-ctf.exe
```

Now to finish off you will need to be sure that you are in the same directory as your package files. 
Run

```
$ cd
```

Then run

```
$ sudo dpkg -i quake2-full-data_37_all.deb quake2-music_37_all.deb
```

Hope this helps you out because it took me ages to find this out for myself!

Cheers